# What does "canRestore" attribute mean in system.xml?

Tags: magento2.2, system.xml

Maybe someone already saw an `<field>` attribute `canRestore="1"`:

```
[...]
<field id="provider"
       translate="label"
       type="text"
       sortOrder="100"
       canRestore="1"
       showInDefault="1">
    <label>Provider</label>
</field>
[...]
```

Any ideas what does it mean?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can show **Use system value** check-box to system configuration by canRestore="1" property in system.xml

[image]

Answer (score 13):

In your config.xml file, you can specify default values for the admin configuration form that you created in system.xml. If a user manually entered a value in one of those fields, they can reset the field to the default value that you specified in config.xml.